# Check via Reflection if Property is computed

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

Please imagine having following two properties inside a class:

```
public string Category { get; set; }
public string DisplayCategory => "SomeCategory"
```

Now I just want to collect all `PropertyInfo` objects where the property itself is not computed

```
var properties = type.GetProperties();
var serializables = properties.Where(p => p.CanRead, true));
```

How do I find out via `Reflection` if a property is a computed one so I can ignore it?

The reason I want to do this, is because I use `Expression Trees` to automatically create queries that are processed via `Entity Framework 6`. Entity Framework only creates columns for non-computed properties and therefore one can't query the computed ones.

See [This Article](http://daveaglick.com/posts/computed-properties-and-entity-framework)

Comment: What exactly would count as "computed"? Anything that isn't a compile-time constant? What about if it were something like reading a static readonly field which isn't a constant, but is initialized just once?

Comment: @Jon Every getter that has some kind of logic behind it instead behaving like a Field. I just want the remaining `Properties` which can be mapped by `Entity Framework` and also queried by using the `Expression Framework`

Comment: What counts as "some kind of logic"? Would two properties that both retrieve the same field count as non-computed, even though they reflect a single piece of state? What about a property where the getter just reads a field, but the setter performs validation? What about a property where the getter reads a field and then takes a property from that, e.g. `public int FooLength => foo.Length;`? What about a property which just reads another property instead of a field? There are all kinds of subtleties possible here...

Comment: Why shouldn´t EF handle properties with a "complex" body? I guess as long as its is a property (eventually decorated with attributes, I´m no expert on EF) EF can handle it, can´t it?

Comment: Which of the two properties should be matched? If both could you provide an example of a property that should *not* be matched?

Comment: I just want the first one. The second one shall be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

The below worked for me.

I was trying to see if I could find a difference between a computed property, and a property with no Set method:

```
public int Computed => 2;
public int NoSet { get; }
```

`PropertyInfo.SetMethod` returns null for both.

Looking at the generated IL of the `get` method, There is a `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` on the `NoSet` property, but not on the `Computed` property:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname instance int32
  get_Computed() cil managed
{
  .maxstack 8

  // [215 32 - 215 33]
  IL_0000: ldc.i4.2
  IL_0001: ret
}

.method public hidebysig specialname instance int32
  get_NoSet() cil managed
{
  .custom instance void [System.Runtime]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor()
    = (01 00 00 00 )
  .maxstack 8

  // [217 28 - 217 32]
  IL_0000: ldarg.0      // this
  IL_0001: ldfld        int32 TestNamespace.TestClass::'<NoSet>k__BackingField'
  IL_0006: ret

}
```

So the check becomes:

```
if (property.SetMethod == null && property.GetMethod.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute)) == null)
    return "Computed Property";
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [DelegateDecompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler) and currently I have to manually add each computed property name to a custom configuration.

It would be nice if the ShouldDecompile method below could automatically determine which properties should be decompiled:

```
  public class CustomDelegateDecompilerConfiguration : Configuration {
    public static CustomDelegateDecompilerConfiguration Instance { get; } = new CustomDelegateDecompilerConfiguration();
    public static void Enable() => Configuration.Configure(Instance);

    public CustomDelegateDecompilerConfiguration() {
      RegisterDecompileableMember<Person, string>(x => x.Name);

      RegisterDecompileableMembers(typeof(string), nameof(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace));

      RegisterDecompileableMembers(typeof(CustomComputedMethods), new[] {
        nameof(CustomComputedMethods.PersonName),
        nameof(CustomComputedMethods.MonthInteger),
        nameof(CustomComputedMethods.WholeMonthsBetween),
        nameof(CustomComputedMethods.WholeYearsBetween)
      });

    }

    public HashSet<MemberInfo> DecompileableMembers { get; } = new HashSet<MemberInfo>();

    public override bool ShouldDecompile(MemberInfo memberInfo) => memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DecompileAttribute), true).Length > 0
      || memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComputedAttribute), true).Length > 0
      || memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute), true).Length > 0
      || DecompileableMembers.Contains(memberInfo)
      //***  Would be nice if auto detection was possible with non-existing methods below ***
      //|| memberInfo.AutoProperty      (One with a backing field automatically generated by the compiler)
      //|| memberInfo.HasExpressionBody (One implemented using the => (lambda) syntax)
      //|| memberInfo.HasFunctionBody   (One implemented using the normal {...} syntax)
      ;

    public override void RegisterDecompileableMember(MemberInfo prop) => DecompileableMembers.Add(prop);

    public void RegisterDecompileableMember<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression) where T : class => RegisterDecompileableMember(expression.Body.GetMemberInfo());

    public void RegisterDecompileableMembers(Type type, params string[] memberNames) {
      foreach(var tmi in type.GetMembers().Where(mi => memberNames.Contains(mi.Name))) {
        DecompileableMembers.Add(tmi);
      }
    }

    public void RegisterDecompileableMembers<T>(params string[] memberNames) where T : class => RegisterDecompileableMembers(typeof(T), memberNames);

  }
```

An  example class:

```
  public class Person {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string AlternativeFirstName { get; set; }

    public string Name => string.Concat(AlternativeFirstName == string.Empty ? FirstName : AlternativeFirstName, " ", LastName);
  }
```

Some example extension Methods:

```
  public static class CustomComputedMethods {
    public static string PersonName(string firstName, string lastName, string knownAs) => (knownAs ?? firstName).Trim() + " " + lastName.Trim();
    public static long MonthInteger(this DateTime d) => checked(d.Year * 12 + d.Month);
    public static int WholeMonthsBetween(this DateTime d, DateTime maxDate) => (int)(maxDate.MonthInteger() - d.MonthInteger() - (d.Day > maxDate.Day ? 1 : 0));
    public static int WholeYearsBetween(this DateTime d, DateTime maxDate) => d.WholeMonthsBetween(maxDate) / 12;
  }
```